# Do Citizens Gather Resources Based On Needs?

Tags: banished

I was playing Banished and just started a new town.  All was doing well until I saw that I had very little stone and iron and needed to build around 4 more houses.  I already had a section of the map selected for my citizens to gather resources so I decided to wait.  Then I noticed that instead of going to the nearest part of the selected area to cut down trees they went and gathered stone and iron that was much further.  This leads me to my question.  Do citizens gather resources based mainly on need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, they're pretty dumb overall. You can however declare certain areas to be of high priority, making citizens focus on them over anything else (building a certain house, cutting a certain resource, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It just seemed weird that they were going out of their way just to get a needed resource.

Comment: Sometimes they'll cut down a tree across the map for construction, freeze half way through, go home, go back to the tree, then move it to a building to use it for construction. Was staring at the little guy scratching my head o.O

Comment: Wow that is completely ridiculous...